# Absolute centered elements get messy on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm making a webpage and I have three elements positioned at the bottom of the page (the viewport) with some offset in two of them. The work great on everything except the **** problematic Internet Explorer. This is what it looks like in chrome or other real browsers (including Opera, Safari, Android default, Mozilla, etc.):

[image]

And from the antique IE:

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
<span class="subtitle-scroll">Scroll para continuar</span>
<img src="css/images/mouse.png" class="mouse">
<img src="css/images/sprite.png" alt="" class="sprite">
```

And the CSS:

```
.subtitle-scroll {
  position:absolute;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:100;
  font-size:24px;
  bottom:50px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:-1;
  margin:auto;
}

.mouse {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:20px;
  z-index:-1;
  margin:auto;
}

.sprite {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://www.pvlts.ga/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `margin: 0 auto` instead of `margin: auto` for `.mouse` and `.sprite` seems to fix the problem with absolute centering for IE. Since you want it bottom-aligned, there's no reason to have auto margins on the top and bottom.

```
.subtitle-scroll {
  position:absolute;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:100;
  font-size:24px;
  bottom:50px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:-1;
  margin:auto;
}

.mouse {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:20px;
  z-index:-1;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.sprite {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```